Linking shared library without also having to link dependencies
If I have a library called libfoo.so, and it depends on other libraries:
libfoo.so ->
            libbar.so
            libsomething.so
            libother.so ->
                          libstuff.so

I now have code I want to link against libfoo.so. Is it possible to link libfoo.so and not have to also supply all of the libraries libfoo.so depends on?
ex:
gcc my.c -o hello-world -lfoo 


I don't think so. This is the kind of thing that's automated by tools like mkdepend.

@Barmar I've never heard of mkdepend, but there are things like pkg-config (.pc) files that libraries can install to describe the C compiler preprocessor and linker options that are required to use the library.

Are you saying you want gcc my.c -o hello-world -lfoo to produce a final executable that you can run even though the further libraries were never supplied to the gcc command? If so, the libraries have to be linked into the executable somehow. What are you thinking for how that happens? That libfoo.so is built to contain them all? That libfoo.so is built with information that tells the linker where to find them? Or something else?

@EricPostpischil Since it's dynamic linking, I think he's just expecting that it will find the dependencies dynamically at execution time.

I solved it. Please see my answer below.

If you can guarantee that the library you are linking against has been properly linked against its dependencies when it was compiled, and if you can guarantee that the libraries it depends on are on your target system, then you can use the linker to ignore unresolved symbols.
(This doesn't exactly mirror the question, but you get the idea)
foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern void bar();

void foo()
{
  printf("foo!\n);
}

bar.c
#include <stdio.h>
void bar()
{
  printf("bar\n");
}

main.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern void foo();

int main()
{
  printf("main\n");
  foo();
  printf("done\n");
  
  return 0;
}

Compile libbar.so (no dependencies)
gcc -fpic -shared bar.c -o libbar.so

Compile libfoo.so (depends on libbar.so)
gcc -fpic -shared foo.c -o libfoo.so -L. -lbar

Compile main (depends on libfoo.so, but we don't want to worry about libbar.so)
gcc main.c -L. -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs -lfoo

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd) ./a.out

If you want to turn the default behavior back on after you have ignored unresolved symbols, you can use "report-all", eg:
gcc main.c -L. -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs -lfoo -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all -lsome_other_library

